# Chart.JS - Couldn't add the margin/spacing between Y-axis labels

Tags: javascript, charts, django-templates, chart.js

1. Any way to Apply margin on Y-axis labels. like I've Genre Names on Y-axis need to add more space/margin among them to see clearly.
2. I almost tried every option which they provided but couldn't get the desired result.
3. ref : https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/
4. I couldn't find any thing that margin's the string values on Y-axis.

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}

{% block sidebar %}
    {{block.super}}
    <div>
        <h3>All Genres Clips</h3>
        <a href="/admin/extra/">Click Here</a>
    </div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.css" />
<style>
#scrollContainer{
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;

}
#chartContainer{
  height: 600px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;

}
</style>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

data = {{ data|safe }};
console.log(data.labels);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async() => {
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

var randomColorGenerator = function () {
    return '#' + (Math.random().toString(16) + '0000000').slice(2, 8);
};

  // Render the chart
  const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data:
    {
        labels: data.labels,
        datasets: [{
         backgroundColor: randomColorGenerator(),
         barPercentage: 0.5,
         barThickness: 1,
         borderWidth: 1,
         //backgroundColor: 'blue',
         data: data.data,
      }]
   },
   options: {
      tooltips: {
         mode: 'index',
         intersect: false
      },
      hover: {
         mode: 'index',
         intersect: false
      },
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      responsive: true,
      legend: {
         display: false,
         position: 'bottom',
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Genre Bar Chart'
        },
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
           gridLines: {
             tickMarkLength: 10,
             display: true,
             drawTicks: true,
             drawOnChartArea: false,
           },
           ticks: {
             fontColor: '#555759',
             fontFamily: 'Lato',
             fontSize: 15,
             autoSkip: false,
             backdropPadding: 500,

           },
        scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              padding: 5,
              fontFamily: 'Lato',
              fontColor: '#555759',
              fontSize: 10,
              fontStyle: 700,
              labelString: 'Genres'
            },
         }],
         xAxes: [{
             gridLines: {
               display: true,
                drawBorder: true,
                lineWidth: 1
             },
           ticks: {
             beginAtZero: true,
             fontColor: '#555759',
             fontFamily: 'Lato',
             fontSize: 10,
           },
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              padding: 5,
              fontFamily: 'Lato',
              fontColor: '#555759',
              fontSize: 10,
              fontStyle: 700,
              labelString: 'Count'
            },

         }]
      }
   }
});
});
</script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div id="scrollContainer">
  <div id="chartContainer">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Render the rest of the ChangeList view -->
{{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

2 things, you are using v2 of chart.js and the documentation you linked is for V3, for the v2 docs you have to specify the specif version like so: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/

For the ticks, chart.js should automatically skip labels so that they dont overlap if you set `autoSkip` to true instead of false, then you can also tell chart.js how many space you want between them with the `autoSkipPadding` property see example underneath. If you really want to show all the labels you have no other option than to make the chart physically bigger since chart.js needs more vertical space te show all labels correctly

Example of skip with extra padding:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          autoSkipPadding: 100
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```